# Intuition behind closed subsets of a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Reading for my exam in real analysis, I struggle with the definition of a closed subset of a metric space.

Consider a metric space $$(X,d)$$

Then consider a subset of this space$$F$$

What the book is trying to convince me of is that F is closed iff a convergent sequence in F always has a limit belonging to F.

The intuition that:

$$x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots\in F$$
$${x_n}\rightarrow a $$
where
$$a\in F$$
for all convergent sequences in F implies that F is closed makes sense to me.

What I am struggling with is understanding the converse. What is it about F containing all of its boundary points that makes it impossible to have a sequence in F converging to some limit outside of F (even though the sequence will never get there)?

Edit:
Is the last sentence in the parenthesis actually the reason I am looking for? That it is impossible to get arbitrarily close to some point outside of F, because when you get really close, then you're not necessarily in F at all?

Comment: Your language after "The intuition that" is a bit confusion. The intuition is that $F$ is closed if for any sequence $x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots\in F$ which converges to some $a\in X$, then $a\in F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm slightly confused about what you think the converse is, and what your definition of a closed set is. You're happy that $$\text{all convergent sequences in $F$ converge to a limit in }F \implies F \text{ is closed}$$ so what you're missing is $$ F \text{ is closed}\implies\text{all convergent sequences in $F$ converge to a limit in }F $$

But "$F$ consisting only of interior points" is equivalent to $F$ being *open*, which doesn't have anything to do with this statement. Since $F$ closed $\iff$ the complement of $F$ is open, one can argue the following if you want to think about interior points:

> Suppose a sequence converges to some point $x\not\in F$. But the complement of $F$ is open, so $x$ is interior to the complement, and there is an open ball $B_x$ which also does not intersect $F$. But then the sequence cannot lie in $F$ since it must eventually lie entirely within $B_x$ since it tends to $x$. **Intuitively**: there's a neighbourhood of the limit which is stuck outside $F$.

*Edit*: If instead you want to think in terms of $F$ containing all 'boundary' points or limit points, then the result you want is true by definition! 'Closed' literally means 'closed under taking limits'.

Comment: You're correct, sorry. I of course meant contains all boundary points. will fix.

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Comment: I got it now, what was confusing me was the actual definitiion of a sequence in F. When keeping in mind that the convergent sequence only contains elements from F, the definition makes intuitive sense. Thanks!

Comment: Relatedly - would you say isolated points are limit points? The text I’m using says they’re not, but just curious if this is conventional or not. (Specifically, the text defines a point x as a limit point of E if it’s adherent to E without x, and where adherent means any open ball has a non-zero intersection with E. So intuitively, isolated points are not limit points… but points on the “edge” of E are limit points)